# jQuery - Filtering <li> with class attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, string, jquery-selectors

I have different checkboxes which onclick filter a set of ~100 li elements based on the li's classes.

Filters:

```
[ ] Rock Checkbox
[ ] Rap Checkbox
[ ] Punk Checkbox
[ ] Country Checkbox

<li class="rock rap punk">...</li>
<li class="rock country">...</li>
```

My javascript looks as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.filter').click(function() {
            var attribute = this.name;
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#champion-list li').each(function(index) {
                    if(!$(this).hasClass(attribute))
                        $(this).hide();
                });
            } else {
                $('#champion-list li').each(function(index) {
                    if(!$(this).hasClass(attribute))
                        $(this).show();
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

So onclick of any checkbox it grabs the name and filters based on class. However, this method is extremely slow. Any better ideas for performance?

Answer (score 6):

The selector is a string, so you can construct it dynamically:

```
$("#champion-list li." + attribute).hide();
```

To select the **li** elements *without* the class:

```
$("#champion-list li :not(." + attribute + ")").hide();
```

Comment: I did that initially but I'm trying to hide all li elements that DONT have the attribute. Negated version of your statement, not sure how though.

Comment: @dbaseman are you sure about the whitespace between li and :not?

Comment: @dbaseman actually that worked perfect. had to clear cache. Thanks again, never knew that existed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

    //cache the list for context
    var list = $('#champion-list')

    //use ".on()" to attach a single handler to the parent
    //onchange, i think, is better since there are keyboard users
    $('filter_parent_container').on('change','.filter',function() {

        var attribute = this.name;

        //directly use the attribute instead of using hasClass()
        if (this.checked) {
            $("li." + attribute,list).hide();
        } else {
            $("li." + attribute,list).show();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: I'd say this is the best solution. However, why do you use `$(this).is(':checked')` when `this.checked` is more than enough?

Answer (score 0):

Cache your selectors. Also you can use `filter()` instead of `each()` and gain some performance there:

```
var $items = $('#champion-list li');
$('.filter').change(function () {
    var that = this,
        $itemsAtt = $items.filter(function () {
            return !$(this).hasClass(that.name);
        });
    $(this).is(':checked') ? $itemsAtt.hide() : $itemsAtt.show();
});
```